# Adobe Illustrator importing large PNG image results in black square

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, import

I'm trying to import a very large PNG image (12k) into Adobe Illustrator for tracing, but when I either drag it on or place it, the image is not imported. Instead there is just a black rectangle with the same dimensions as the image:

[image]

I'm on Illustrator CC19 on Windows 10.

The original PNG image looks like this:
[image]

Comment: well 12k pixels? what is the size? if it can be uploaded please share with us so we can replicate issue! it seems your image is around 1.2k !

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Can you share the actual original image instead of a screenshot of it?